# How to Drag&Drop images from browser to Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspasteboard

I need to drag images from browser to a mac app. When dragging images from img tag, it works perfectly but when there is a link between img, it doesn’t work.  NSPasteboard receives NSURL from link, not from img source. Drag feedback shows image, so I think it’s sending image data. I’ve checked propertyListForType from NSPasteboard, and it only contains link href.

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    if ([sender draggingSource] == nil){
        NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard]; 
        if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType]){
            NSURL* file = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard: [sender draggingPasteboard]];
            //if <img> tag, file is src. If <a><img></a>, it’s link href

            //DOWNLOAD image here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the URL or would you be happy with just the image?

Comment: If I have image I will be happy too :) But I need to know the file extension, not just TIFF representation

Answer (score 0):

There should be a variety of types offered on the NSPasteboard. The first thing I do whenever I’m writing any pasteboard receiving code is write some debugging code that dumps ALL the available types and their values I get when a drag happens into my view. Then I just pick and choose the ones I want.

As a start, just

```
NSLog(@“types %@“, pboard.types);
```

I’ll leave it as an exercise to dump the values. :)